# UITableView won't scroll when added as a subview

Tags: uiview, uitableview, addsubview

I have a UIView called tableContainer, and I am adding a UITableView from the class WidgetTable as a subview of tableContainer, but although it adds successfully, the tableview won't scroll. How can I make it scroll?

```
 WidgetTable *widTable = [[WidgetTable alloc] initWithNibName:@"WidgetTable" bundle:nil];


    //ADD WIDGET TABLE TO SUBVIEW
    [tableContainer addSubview:widTable.view];
    [tableContainer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 77, 320, 460)];
```